# Structure Navigation with 3 possible Link Types using Nav tag

Tags: structure, navigation, custom-fieldtype, custom-field

I'd like to build a Structure that can be used to output the main site navigation; each "entry" in the Structure would have three custom fields (types): Category, Entries, URL

[This question is close to what I want](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14019/navigation-structure-and-uri-problems), except it's not using Nav; I want children, so I think I need Nav? Plus I couldn't get that code to work anyway.

Based on [other questions](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9942/navigation-structure-usage-woes) and the docs, I have this:

```
{% set pages = craft.entries.section('navDropDownMenu').all() %}
<ul>
    {% nav page in pages %}
        <li>
            {% if page.entriesFieldLink %}
                <a href="{{ page.entriesFieldLink.first().url|default }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
            {% elseif page.urlFieldLink %}
                <a href="{{{{ page.urlFieldLink.first().url|default }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
            {% else %}
                <a href="{{ page.category.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
         {% endif %}
            {% ifchildren %}
                <ul>
                    {% children %}
                </ul>
            {% endifchildren %}
        </li>
    {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

The only thing that works here is the Category link, except it should be a child but it isn't. I'm new to Craft so I'm probably doing something basic wrong, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am doing something similar in using a Structure for the main navigation.  Below is what I have.  Hope it helps!

```
{% set menu = craft.entries.section('navMain').all() %}
<ul> 
{% nav link in menu %}
    <li>
    {% if link.menuEntry|length %}
        {% if craft.app.request.absoluteUrl ==  link.menuEntry[0].url %}
        <a href="{{ link.menuEntry[0].url }}" class="active">{{ link.title }}</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{{ link.menuEntry[0].url }}">{{ link.title }}</a>
         {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        {% if craft.app.request.absoluteUrl ==  link.menuCustomURL %}
            <a href="{{ link.menuCustomURL }}" class="active">{{ link.title }}</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{{ link.menuCustomURL }}">{{ link.title }}</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% ifchildren %}
        <ul>
            {% children %}
        </ul>
    {% endifchildren %}
    </li> 
{% endnav %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Nevermind, I had somehow removed the parent item. This DOES output the children correctly. Thanks! ---Thanks, this gets the links to output correctly (which I appreciate), but it doesn't structure the children properly (no sub UL for the children).---