# Get the Sub-Category Link from Category field in a Structure (output with Nav tag)

Tags: categories, navigation

I am creating a *Structure* for the main navigation that has two possible choices for the Link: **Entries field** or a **Categories field**. The answer I received here showed me [how to setup the basics](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/37086/structure-navigation-with-3-possible-link-types-using-nav-tag) but if the Category page I want to link to is a Sub Category, it will only link to the Parent.

```
{% set menu = craft.entries.section('navDropDownMenu').all() %}
<ul>
    {% nav link in menu %}
        <li>
        {% if link.entriesURL|length %}
            {% if craft.app.request.absoluteUrl ==  link.entriesFieldURL[0].url %}
                <a href="{{ link.entriesFieldURL[0].url }}" class="active">{{ link.title }}</a>
            {% else %}
                <a href="{{ link.entriesFieldURL[0].url }}">{{ link.title }}</a>
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            {% if craft.app.request.absoluteUrl ==  link.categoryFieldURL[0].url %}
                <a href="{{ link.categoryFieldURL[0].url }}" class="active">{{ link.title }}</a>
            {% else %}
                <a href="{{ link.categoryFieldURL[0].url }}">{{ link.title }}</a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %} 
            {% ifchildren %}
                <ul>
                    {% children %}
                </ul>
            {% endifchildren %}
        </li>
    {% endnav %}
```

So what I'm trying to figure out is, if I have a category setup like this:

```
-Shoes
    -Tennis
```

in the context of using the Nav Tag (as above), how do I get the link to 'Tennis' and not 'Shoes'?

I know you can output a nav of Categories, but I wanted to use a Structure if possible because the navigation has a mixture of categories and links to internal pages, and they are mixed together in the navigation as far as sorting goes.

Answer (score 2):

In short, don't use the `{% nav %}` tag as it's not flexible enough for what you need.

Assuming your fields are called `entriesFieldURL` and `categoriesFieldURL`, try something like this:

```twig
{# Fetch the current page ID to use for your active class later on. If entry exists, we are on an entry page, else, category page or NULL fallback #}
{% set currentPageId = entry.id ?? category.id ?? null %}

{# Fetch your entries and eager-load children #}
{% set menu = craft.entries()
    .section('navDropDownMenu')
    .level(1)
    .with('children')
    .all() %}

<ul>
{%- for item in menu -%}
    
    {# Set a link object which switches based on whether you have a category or an entry #}
    {%- set link = item.entriesFieldURL|length ? item.entriesFieldURL[0] : item.categoriesFieldURL.leaves()[0] -%}
    <li>
        
        {# Output the link and add active class base on the current page when needed #}
        <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="{{ link.id == currentPageId ? 'active' }}">{{ link.title }}</a>
        
        {# Does this item have children? #}
        {%- if item.children -%}
        <ul>
            {%- for item in item.children -%}
            
            {# As above, set a link object which switches based on whether you have a category or an entry #}
            {%- set link = item.entriesFieldURL|length ? item.entriesFieldURL[0] : item.categoriesFieldURL.leaves()[0] -%}
            <li>
                
                {# And again, output the link and add active class when needed #}
                <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="{{ link.id == currentPageId ? 'active' }}">{{ link.title }}</a>
            </li>
            {%- endfor -%}
        </ul>
        {%- endif -%}
    </li>
{%- endfor -%}
</ul>
```

As you can see, there's some repetition in there which you could solve by using [a short macro](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/twig-primer.html#macros) to build the `<a>` tags making the complete thing:

```twig
{# Fetch the current page ID to use for your active class later on. If entry exists, we are on an entry page, else, category page or NULL fallback #}
{% set currentPageId = entry.id ?? category.id ?? null %}

{# Fetch your entries and eager-load children #}
{% set menu = craft.entries()
    .section('navDropDownMenu')
    .level(1)
    .with('children')
    .all() %}

{% macro linkItem(item, currentPageId) %}
    {%- set link = item.entriesFieldURL|length ? item.entriesFieldURL[0] : item.categoriesFieldURL.leaves()[0] -%}
    <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="{{ link.id == currentPageId ? 'active' }}">{{ link.title }}</a>
{% endmacro %}

<ul>
{%- for item in menu -%}
    <li>
        {{ _self.linkItem(item, currentPageId) }}
        {%- if item.children -%}
        <ul>
            {%- for item in item.children -%}
                <li>
                    {{ _self.linkItem(item, currentPageId) }}
                </li>
            {%- endfor -%}
        </ul>
        {%- endif -%}
    </li>
{%- endfor -%}
</ul>
```

You could further refine but hopefully, this gets you started :)

Comment: This has the same problem, it can't handle sub-categories (it will only link to the top level).

Comment: Do you mean if you choose a subcategory in your categoriesFieldURL?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is, if I have a Category Field, and the category I choose is a subcategory (like my example Shoe > Tennis) Then what appears is only the Parent category, which I don't want in that case. Put another way, I'm accessing product pages by category, so what I need from a Navigation element is to link to the Parent as well as Sub categories, depending on the nav item. My idea with this Structure was that I could have some Nav items that are Entries and Some that are Categories (parent and sub), but only the Parent outputs.

Comment: I just re-read your question and I think I misunderstood. Yes, if the choice is a sub-category, it ignores that choice and outputs the Parent.

Comment: I changed the code in the answer, could you give that another go?

Comment: I spoke too soon. That works fine if it is a sub-category, but if the link is a Parent category it outputs nothing. Basically the idea is, I want to create a structure for the nav, some of the nav links will be a Parent Category, some of them will be a Sub Category, and some will be a link to an Entry.

Comment: I just tried to test this and it works for me. Are you using the macro example and if so, how deep are the categories?

Comment: Yes, copied and pasted your Macro code. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but if link is top level category it outputs an empty anchor element. I'll dig a little more and see if I missed something, but I might just kill the idea. But thanks for the help with it.